# Legend doesn't show all line's on line Rgraph

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I'm using Rgraph to make a line graph with multiple line's on it. The problem i'm having is that some graphs i'm making can have over 30 lines on them which means the legend doesn't show all the lines displayed on the graph.

I've looked through the properties of the Rgraph but can't find something that would help me. Is there a way that I can display all this information on the legend in some way, ie a scrollbar.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML key. That isn't constrained by the size of the canvas. Or make your own labels with HTML.